# how to add to array other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

how can i add publicHolidays to events , this my code but not working , what is wrong always the events array is only listLeave .

```
  const events = useMemo(
    () =>
      leavesListData.list.map(({ id, absenceTypeName, approvalStatusCd, startDate, endDate }) => {
        return {
          key: id,
          title: absenceTypeName,
          start: startDate,
          end: endDate,
          status: getLeaveStatusColor(approvalStatusCd),
          isPublicHoliday: false,
        };
      }),
    [leavesListStatus]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (statusPublicHolidays === RequestStatus.resolved) {
      publicHolidays?.map((event) => {
        events.push({
          key: Number(event.eventId),
          title: event.name,
          start: event.startDate.toString(),
          end: event.endDate.toString(),
          isPublicHoliday: true,
          status: 'gray',
        });
      });
    }
  }, [statusPublicHolidays]);
```

Comment: Which one is not working, `useMemo` part or `useEffect` part?

Comment: I don't know why `[leavesListStatus]` deps needs

Comment: You can't mutate the `events` by `events.push()`, because `events` is a calculated value.

Comment: first ```useMemo``` then ```useEffect``` then agin ```useMemo```